# Pass event from viewContainerRef to entry parent Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript

Im wondering how you can pass an event from a dynamic `viewContainerRef` component to its `entry` parent??

My set up is as follows

**main.component.html**

```
<div #entry></div>
```

**main.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef, ComponentFactoryResolver } from '@angular/core';

import { RemoveDataComponent } from '...';

@Component...

export class ...

@ViewChild('entry', { read: ViewContainerRef }) entry: ViewContainerRef;

...

openComponent() {
    const removeDataFactory = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(RemoveDataComponent);
    const component = this.entry.createComponent(removeDataFactory);
} 

clearComponent() {
    this.viewContainerRef.clear();
}
```

remove-data.component.ts

```
clear() {
  ...
}
```

basically I want the clear button in the dynamically added component to clear the `viewContainerRef`

now I know how you would normally pass the event using an eventEmitter does it work the same way? or do I have to do something else?? I'm aware I could use a shared service to make the call but seems like a bit of a work around...

any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Just create EventEmitter and subscribe to it manually in parent component or pass callback to dynamic component